# Android Wear : launching an activty in the handheld on clicking notification action button in wear

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I want to start an activity in the handheld app and send some data  when the user clicks on notification action button in the wear. I am using below code to build the notification in the wear.

```
public Notification buildNotification(Context context) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        return buildBasicNotification(context).extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                .setContentIcon(R.drawable.content_icon_small)
                .setContentIconGravity(Gravity.START))
                .addAction(new Notification.Action(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                        "Action A", pendingIntent))


                .build();
    }
```

Is it possible to start the activity in handheld through pending intent only or should we start an service/activity in the wear on clicking action button and from that activity/service send message to the device through message api. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you creating the notification from your handheld app or from your Wearable app?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am creating the notification in wearable app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Wearable app is completely separate from the handheld app, with the only communication path being using the message/data APIs so unfortunately there is no way to directly trigger an action on the handheld from a notification generated on the Wearable.

You are correct in the approach that needs to be taken, however:

1. Create a PendingIntent for your action that starts a service (an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) works perfectly)
2. In that service:

   1. Connect to a GoogleApiClient
   2. If a connected device is found, start a [ConfirmationActivity](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html#show-confirmation) using an `OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION` (this displays a visible sign to your user that your app is opening something on their handheld)
   3. Send a message to the connected device using a set path (say, `notification/open`)
3. In your handheld app, implement a [WearableListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) which will receive your message in the background:

   1. In the [onMessageReceived()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onMessageReceived(com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent)) call, check the received message's path for the path you set (i.e., `messageEvent.getPath().equals("notification/open")`)
   2. If it matches, then start the appropriate activity on your handheld.

This approach is used in [Muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei) when starting the watch face having never activated the live wallpaper in the handheld app. Code covering each of these sections can be found on the [Github repository.](https://github.com/romannurik/muzei)

Specifically, steps 1 and 2 can be found in [ActivateMuzeiIntentService](https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/wearable/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/ActivateMuzeiIntentService.java):

```
public static void showNotification(Context context) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    // Set up your notification as normal

    // Create the launch intent, in this case setting it as the content action
    Intent launchMuzeiIntent = new Intent(context, 
        ActivateMuzeiIntentService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, 
        launchMuzeiIntent, 0);
    builder.addAction(new Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_open_on_phone,
            context.getString(R.string.common_open_on_phone), pendingIntent)
            .extend(new Notification.Action.WearableExtender()
                    .setAvailableOffline(false))
            .build());
    builder.extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
            .setContentAction(0));

    // Send the notification with notificationManager.notify as usual
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Open on Phone action
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    ConnectionResult connectionResult =
            googleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient.");
        return;
    }
    List<Node> nodes =  Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient)
        .await().getNodes();
    // Ensure there is a connected device
    if (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
        // Show the open on phone animation
        Intent openOnPhoneIntent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
        openOnPhoneIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        openOnPhoneIntent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE,
                ConfirmationActivity.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(openOnPhoneIntent);
        // Clear the notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        // Send the message to the phone to open Muzei
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, node.getId(),
                    "notification/open", null).await();
        }
    }
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

And then the step 3 on the handheld side are handled by [MuzeiWearableListenerService](https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/MuzeiWearableListenerService.java):

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    String path = messageEvent.getPath();
    if (path.equals("notification/open")) {

        // In this case, we launch the launch intent for the application
        // but it could be anything
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent mainIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
            getPackageName());
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```